# To find which image out of the two were clicked and report it to Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, image

I'm not very new to programming nor am I a prodigy or a maestro at it. Now I'm trying to make a website like [Facesmash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Facebook#Facemash) where

1. two images show up randomly from the respective arrays and
2. an up-vote is given to the image on which user clicked
3. the result is stored as a vote in database

Now I've done with the first part and will do with the third as well with php.
Where I'm facing a problem is the 2nd part.
My code in JavaScript looks like this..

```
var imagesArray1 = ["a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg","d.jpg","e.jpg"];

var imagesArray2 = ["f.jpg","g.jpg","h.jpg","i.jpg","j.jpg"];



function displayImage(){


document.getElementById('nextButton').value="NEXT";
 var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArra1.length));
var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray2.length));

document.canvas1.src = imagesArray1[num1];
document.canvas2.src = imagesArray2[num2];     }
```

As you can see.. I've created two arrays and a random Image is generated from both the two. Now to create a polling system, one solution would be to take two variables p and q. 
 `p=num1` and `q=num2`
 If image1 is clicked, the php code reports "p" and value of the index `num1` to the DB
If image2 is clicked, php code sends "q" and value of the index `num2`
`num1` and `num2` are the randomly generated indices of the image arrays. I'll do with the php part, Just wanted help in this.
 Any other code solution would be appreciated. Thanks a ton for time and help

Comment: are these images indexes/ID's stored in db as well?

Comment: no the images indices aren't  pre-stored in DB. But on click of any of the image (Image1 or Image2), I  want to store the index of the selected image in DB

Comment: is there any image information store in the database at all? and

Comment: No. No image info pre-stored in dB. The images are fetched from the server

Comment: And what exactly are u storing on the database? aren't you saving the upvote of that image?

Comment: yes I want to store the upvote for the image clicked by the user on db

Comment: Then you also need to have the data of the images on the database as well

Comment: what columns do u have in the table that u wanna store on?

Comment: In the table, I have 2 columns.1 named p/q and the other named index. if image1 is clicked I wanna store p and the index of the image (num1) while if second image is clicked, I wanna store q and the index of that image (num2)

Comment: I guess these two columns are enough to find out which image was clicked. Also note that the two arrays have all different images. so p will tell image from Array 1 was clicked. q will tell image from array 2 was clicked. num1 and num2 give the indices of the images from the respective arrays

Comment: did you get what am i trying to say? @Masivuye?

Comment: yes I think do understand , I'm preparing something that u can test

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot

Comment: check below answer

Comment: Got the code. Letme test it

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write this up :

This is what I suggest you should display your images.

```
<img src="pathToImage1Array" data-name="p" id="num1_Image1IndexFROMTheArrayVariable">

<img src="pathToImage2Array" data-name="q" id="num2_Image2IndexFROMTheArrayVariable">
```

Please note.

Id needs to be unique for each image that will come from the array.

so we need to make our ID for the image unique.. with a dynamic data. so we will have a prefix for each image ID that will come up from the array.

in this case we have num1_ then the string after the underscore (_) will be replaced by the variable that stores index of each image so if the index of the image is 8 then num1_8 this changes as the image changes.

Then you will need to send ajax request to some php script when the image is clicked.

then your ajax :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){

        //getting data of the 1st image.. that have a dyamic ID.
        $('[id^="num1_"]').on('click',function(){

            var index = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]; //get index  of the clicked image
            var action = "firstimage";
            var image = $(this).data('name');
            $.ajax({

                type : "POST",
                data : {imageIndex:index,action:action,:image:image},
                url  : "pathTophpfile/phpfile.php",
                dataType :"json",
                encode : true,
                success : function(response){

                    if(response == "ok"){

                        alert("vote casted");
                    }else{

                        alert(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        });


        $('[id^="num2_"]').on('click',function(){

            var index = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]; //get the index of the clicked image
            var action = "secondimage";
            var image = $(this).data('name');

            $.ajax({

                type : "POST",
                data : {imageIndex:index,action:action},
                url  : "pathTophpfile/phpfile.php",
                dataType :"json",
                encode : true,
                success : function(response){

                    if(response == "ok"){

                        alert("vote casted");
                    }else{

                        alert(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

then your server side :

I'm not sure which API you comfortable with `PDO/MYSQLI` I did `mysqli` prepared statements :

```
<?php

$conn = new mysli("..."); // the staff you should know already

function image1($conn)
{

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"):
        $imageIndex = $_POST['imageIndex'];
        $image      = $_POST['image'];
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT into YourTable (`p/q`,index) VALUES(?,?)");
        $sql->bind_param("si", $image, $imageIndex);
        if ($sql->execute()) {

            echo json_decode("ok");
        } else {

            echo json_decode("Error : " . $conn->error);
        }
    endif;
}


function image2($conn)
{

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"):
        $imageIndex = $_POST['imageIndex'];
        $image      = $_POST['image'];
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT into YourTable (`p/q`,index) VALUES(?,?)");
        $sql->bind_param("si", $image, $imageIndex);
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            echo json_decode("ok");
        } else {
            echo json_decode("Error : " . $conn->error);
        }
    endif;
}

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

    $action = $_POST['action'];

    switch ($action) {
        case 'firstimage':
            image1($conn);
            break;

        case 'secondimage':
            image2($conn);
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by...img src="pathToImage1Array" ?? What is path to Image1Array? Also.. there are about 50 images in both the arrays.. what id of the img element should I kep ?

Comment: $.ajax({

              type : "POST",
                data : {action:action, image:image},
                url  :  "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\phpfile.php",
                dataType :"json",
                encode : true,
                success : function(response){

                    if(response == "ok"){

                        alert("vote casted");
                    }else{

                        alert(response);
                    }
                }
            });

Comment: This $.ajax part I guess isnt working in my script tag

Comment: @ManavSethi no not the full c:// path just the path to the file from the page that have ajax

Comment: can you show me how do you display your images? and how do u populate em

Comment: This the my whole original project folder ..you can view the source code of the index.html

Comment: did you see what I sent?

Comment: haven't got any chance yet been super busy @ManavSethi